Error using SwapRouter02 CALL_EXCEPTION
I am trying to exchange WETH to LINK on the sepolia BASE network, but it returns Error: transaction failed [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ]
I am using SwapRouter02 according to what uniswap says
https://docs.uniswap.org/contracts/v3/reference/deployments/base-deployments
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

const { abi: V3SwapRouterABI } = require('@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/SwapRouter.sol/SwapRouter.json')
const ROUTER_ADDRESS = '0x94cC0AaC535CCDB3C01d6787D6413C739ae12bc4'
const WETH_ADDRESS = '0x4200000000000000000000000000000000000006'
const TOKEN_OUT_ADDRESS = '0xE4aB69C077896252FAFBD49EFD26B5D171A32410';

WALLET_ADDRESS = ''
WALLET_SECRET = '';
ALCHEMY_URL = '';

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(ALCHEMY_URL);
const signer = new ethers.Wallet(WALLET_SECRET, provider);

const router = new ethers.Contract(ROUTER_ADDRESS, V3SwapRouterABI)

const inputAmount = ethers.utils.parseEther("0.0005");

async function main() {
    const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 10);

    const params = {
        tokenIn: WETH_ADDRESS,
        tokenOut: TOKEN_OUT_ADDRESS,
        fee: 3000,
        recipient: WALLET_ADDRESS,
        deadline: deadline,
        amountIn: inputAmount,
        amountOutMinimum: 0,
        sqrtPriceLimitX96: 0,
    }
    const data = router.interface.encodeFunctionData("exactInputSingle", [params]);
    const txArgs = {
        to: ROUTER_ADDRESS,
        from: WALLET_ADDRESS,
        data: data,
        value: inputAmount,
        gasLimit: "1000000"
    }
    console.log("sending tx");
    const tx = await signer.sendTransaction(txArgs);
    const receipt = await tx.wait();
    console.log("complete");

}
main();


If your address is "0x00112B...." (same token/value, only failures) the sig being passed doesn't exist at the router, it's creating the sig from arguments being passed inside a tuple.  exactInputSingle((address,address,uint24,address,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint160)) instead of exactInputSingle(address,address,uint24,address,uint256,uint256,uint256,uint160) .
